# Flutter - How to use enum with const in a class

Tags: flutter, enums

I am fairly new to Flutter and have made my first Reusable Widget. Below is a cleaner example on what I am trying to do.

My enum:

```
enum StreamBoxSize {
  small(9),
  medium(15),
  large(18);

  final double borderRadius;
  const StreamBoxSize(this.borderRadius);
}
```

I am trying to give each enum value a default border radius value, so if I am choosing StreamBoxSize.small the border radius of my container is going to be 9.

My class looks like this:

```
class StreamBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const StreamBox({
    super.key,
    this.size = StreamBoxSize.large,
  });
  final StreamBoxSize size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(**borderRadius**),
          topRight: Radius.circular(**borderRadius**),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(**borderRadius**),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(**borderRadius**),
        ),
...
```

I have marked in bold the value that of course doesnt work becaues my class dont know what borderRadius is. Any idea how to make it work? The value I want here is dynamic so everything will be 9 if I have choosen this:

```
StreamBox(size: StreamBoxSize.small),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you already tried and there's something I'm missing, but why setting

```
Radius.circular(size.borderRadius)
```

for each side won't work?

After all, `StreamBoxSize.borderRadius` is public and should be visible inside the `build` method...

Comment: I hade not tried that, and it did work. Thank you so much :)